# Simulate a click or add an anchor to a image gallery on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, redirect, gallery

I am having a hard time trying to find the answer to my problem. I have created my aunt a website on Wordpress and I have a image gallery that is using [filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Haq1m.png)
(see image attached).

I would like the users to be redirected to a specific filter (Love, Amy winehouse, etc.) while clicking on the homepage of my website, as the fitlers redirect users to the all pictures section by default.

I am not a developper so I'm not too sure how I can do it properly. If someone can provide me help with this issue that would be great.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best,
Antoine

Comment: Hi @Antoine, can you share the website live link, this could be achievable with some edit in the JS files

Comment: hi @GABYKARAM, thanks a lot for the answer. I've managed to find another solution. Thanks for taking the time to reply to my answer. Antoine